# Why cant I instantiate my class, but I can in another project?

Tags: c#, xna

I am trying to instantiate my "Boundries" class but it doesn't show up when I type it out in my main class. However, i added the class to a past project and it all worked fine so it must not be anything to do with my code. I am new to c# and was wondering if there was an easy fix for this.

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace Game1
{
    class Boundries
    {
        public int boundY, boundX, boundWidth, boundLength;

        public Boundries(Rectangle bRectangle, int intX, int intY, int intWidth, int intLength)
        {
            boundY = intY;
            boundX = intX;
            boundWidth = intWidth;
            boundLength = intLength;
        }
    }
}
```

This class works perfectly fine in my past project but not in my new one.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Is the class in the project? Is the class a nested/private class? Is the class compiled, the compiled .dll/.exe used as reference and the using statement used?

Comment: where is your main-class?

Answer (score 2):

According to this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)

> Classes and structs declared directly within a namespace (in other
>   words, that aren't nested within other classes or structs) can be
>   either public or internal. Internal is the default if no access
>   modifier is specified.

You can't instantiate it from other projects because you didn't put "public" for your class.

```
public class Boundries
{
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. However, I have added public in front of my class and I still cant see it.

Comment: What is the code of your other project where you try to reference `Game1`? @sa1addd

Comment: @sa1addd, can you show your other project code? Where do you instantiate it?

Comment: OPs problem is exactly the opposite. While he/she **is** able to instantiate the class from other project, it does not work from project where the class lives.

Comment: If he/she can't instantiate from same project, that should be because of different namespace, but forget to include it.